# Why doesn't raise "go test -run testThatDoesNotExist" an error?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I just stumbled over a situation that made me curious. I spent half an hour to figure out why `go test -run testWrittenWithSmallT` is not executing my test. Except that I spelled it with a small **t** instead of **T** I noticed that `go test` passes if the given test method does not exist.

Little background: Initially I was wondering why my tests are not printing `fmt.Println` to `stdout`, or at least I thought that was the error. Only after a while I found out that the test is not executed at all.

So I am wondering, is there any reason why that should pass silently?

Examples `go` file:

```
package helloworld

import(
  "fmt"
  "testing"
)

func testWithSmallT(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("test with small t executed")
}

func TestWithCapitalT(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("test with capital T executed")
}
```

Test results:

```
$go test -run testWithSmallT
PASS
ok      starsheriff.net/helloworld  0.004s

$go test -run TestWithCapitalT
test with capital T executed
PASS
ok      starsheriff.net/helloworld  0.003s

$go test -run TestDoesNotExist
PASS
ok      starsheriff.net/helloworld  0.004s
```

Comment: on the side: add -v to get the fmt.Println of your Tests

Comment: yes, I usually do. I really like the `t.Log()` and `t.Logf()` methods! Omitted it here since it has no effect on the example.

Comment: Well, with the `-run` flag you are explicitly selecting which tests to run. If you select none, I think it's correct to execute no test without raising any error.

Comment: Otherwise it would not be possible to execute benchmarks only as you have to turn tests off in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Go now emits a warning when the `-run` regexp doesn't match anything.

```
$go test -run TestDoesNotExist
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
ok      starsheriff.net/helloworld  0.179s
```

I think the reasoning before was that because you are passing a regular expression with the `-run` flag, if you pass something that doesn't match any tests it should just pass, since technically all (zero) tests passed, and nothing failed.

It was probably better before to pass the verbose (`-v`) flag with `-run`, that way you could always see which tests were run, not just which tests failed. In verbose mode, go test will always print out a message for passing tests, so at least you'd see there were no tests run at all. With the warning message, there's no longer the same need to run tests with `-v`.